# how does tomcat know which certificaate to provide

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, keytool

I'm using tomcat server as a servlet container, I wanted the connections to this server to be secure "https" so I created a keystore, using the command `keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -keystore tomcat.jks` I filled the prompt questions and then generated a CSR from this key and signed it using another certificate, then I imported the signed certificate to my keystore, but after running the server, and check the certificate came to the browser, I find that it is the same as the `privateKeyentry` in the keystore not the signed certificate, it even have the SHA1 finger print of the entry that matches the `privatekeyentry`.
my question is should the tomcat provide the signed certificate in this case? and why it is providing the privatekeyentry when asked for a certificate, and what it will do if there is more than one certificate in the keystore file, and more than one private key entry?

Comment: `keytool` shows the _public key_ (or certificate) of the entry that has type `privateKeyEntry` (more info about different entry types in the [keystore docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html). The same public key is visible from the browser. You'd need a tool like OpenSSL for extracting the actual private key.

Comment: How did you import the signed certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the signed certificate using the same alias as when you generated the private/public key pair. Otherwise the certificate isn't associated with the private key, which is required for SSL, and the original certificate-wrapper for the private key is used instead.

Answer (score 2):

I have multiple certificates in my tomcat keystore. Each of my <Connector> elements in my server.xml refers to the same keystore but a different certificate. When you import the certificate into the keystore, you should specify an alias for that entry and tell the connector which alias to use.

```
<Connector ... keyAlias="myalias" ... >
```

Comment: Why would you not store the private key that matches the server's public key, in the keystore? Where else would you store it? The server needs it for decrypting TLS traffic.

Comment: You *must* store the private key belonging to the certificate in the KeyStore along with the certificate. Otherwise To,cat can't use it as a server certificate. One of the SSL handshakr steps requires a digital signature signed by that private key, to prove that that server is the owner of that certificate.